# Add different CSS to every option of ui-select

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ui-select

I want to add different CSS to every option of `ui-select` as given in the image so that every option is shown in different `text-color`

[image]

Here is the Plunk with the code: [**Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tsIehvYg4ZwchMZUTMAS?p=preview)

I also tried with giving different `li` as shown here

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in (itemArray) track by item.id">
   <li style="color:green;">Pending</li>
   <li style="color:red;">Rejected</li>
   <li style="color:blue;">Approved</li>
</ui-select-choices>
```

but when I select the item the `css` won't persist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have associated color for each item in the array. Like this:

```
$scope.itemArray = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Pending', color: 'green'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Rejected', color: 'red'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Approved', color: 'blue'},
];
```

And, then in the `ui-select`,

```
<ui-select-match>
    <span style="color: {{$select.selected.color}}" ng-bind="$select.selected.name | limitTo: 20"></span>
</ui-select-match>

<ui-select-choices repeat="item in (itemArray) track by item.id">
    <span style="color: {{item.color}}" ng-bind="item.name"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

[**working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/u7ZYavi4S49xfWAAHKnq?p=preview)

Comment: The selected item still does not have color.

Comment: @maenolis thanks for noticing, I have updated (had forgotten to save)

Comment: @AayushiJain no prob, glad it could help a bit!

Comment: @Taysumi oh! Not sure what could go wrong on IE 11. Can you Ctrl+F5 plunker or open in private/incognito mode?

Comment: @tanmay Oh well. I don't really care to be honest. I tried it on my mobile with chrome, works like a charm. I use IE only because I have to (company). Nice solution. +1

Comment: @Taysumi no prob, glad you liked it!